# opendkim no signing table match for no signature data

Tags: postfix, dkim, opendkim, milter

I got an error when I try to install and config opendkim :

```
no signing table match for 'contact@domain.com'
no signature data
```

**opendkim.conf** :

```
# This is a basic configuration that can easily be adapted to suit a standard
# installation. For more advanced options, see opendkim.conf(5) and/or
# /usr/share/doc/opendkim/examples/opendkim.conf.sample.

# Log to syslog
Syslog          yes
# Required to use local socket with MTAs that access the socket as a non-
# privileged user (e.g. Postfix)
UMask           022

# Sign for example.com with key in /etc/mail/dkim.key using
# selector '2007' (e.g. 2007._domainkey.example.com)
#Domain         *
#KeyFile        /etc/mail/dkim.key
#Selector       default

# Commonly-used options; the commented-out versions show the defaults.
#Canonicalization   simple
Mode            sv
SubDomains      yes
#ADSPDiscard        no

# Always oversign From (sign using actual From and a null From to prevent
# malicious signatures header fields (From and/or others) between the signer
# and the verifier.  From is oversigned by default in the Debian pacakge
# because it is often the identity key used by reputation systems and thus
# somewhat security sensitive.
OversignHeaders     From

# List domains to use for RFC 6541 DKIM Authorized Third-Party Signatures
# (ATPS) (experimental)

#ATPSDomains        example.com

KeyTable           /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
SigningTable       /etc/opendkim/SigningTable
ExternalIgnoreList /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts      /etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts

LogWhy                  Yes
UserID                  opendkim:opendkim
Socket                  inet:8891@localhost
PidFile                 /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
```

I use this script for manage my domains :

```
for domain in domain.com domain2.com domain3.com
 do
  mkdir -p /etc/opendkim/keys/$domain
  cd /etc/opendkim/keys/$domain
  opendkim-genkey -r -d $domain
  chown opendkim:opendkim default.private
  echo "default._domainkey.$domain $domain:default:/etc/opendkim/keys/$domain/default.private" >> /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
  echo "$domain default._domainkey.$domain" >> /etc/opendkim/SigningTable
 done
```

I try :

```
sudo chown opendkim:opendkim -R /etc/opendkim
sudo chmod 770 -R /etc/opendkim
```

or use `refile` on `SigningTable`, but nothing change...

I put in **/etc/default/opendkim**

```
SOCKET="inet:8891:localhost"
```

config added for DKIM :

```
#DKIM
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
milter_mail_macros {mail_addr} {client_addr} {client_name} {auth_authen}
```

***so what's wrong with my config ?***

Versions :

postfix :

```
mail_version = 3.1.8
```

dovecot --version

```
 2.2.27 (c0f36b0)
```

opendkim -V

```
opendkim: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0
```

Comment: https://github.com/sovereign/sovereign/issues/510 may be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your SigningTable contains wildcards (e.g. `*@mydomain.com` , where `*`  to match all users is a wildcard), you should prefix it with **refile:** in the **opendkim.conf** file, like this:

`SigningTable       refile:/etc/opendkim/SigningTable`